# Routing in app with firebase doesn`t work correct

Tags: angular, firebase, service, routes, components

**https://github.com/Wilkuuu/Biblio**

In Books component in html i`ve :

```
<a 
  routerLink="/books/{{book.id}}" 
  class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
</a>
```

in app-routing :

```
{ path: 'book/:id', component: BookDetailComponent }
```

In URL i see an id from firebase, but the path provides me to :

```
{ path: '**' , component: NotfoundComponent },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a look at your route config:

```
{ path: 'book/:id', component: BookDetailComponent }
```

The route that you should be using is `book/` and not `books/`

```
routerLink="/books/{{book.id}}"
```

should be

```
routerLink="/book/{{book.id}}"
```

And yeah, as mentioned by Andrei, the catch-all route(the one with `path: '**'`) should be the last route in your route config.

Comment: also, the match-all pattern should be the last one in the array of Routes.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc problem solved. {path: '**' , component: NotfoundComponent}, must be the last one. Ty !